# ModelForm has no model class specified in django

Tags: python, django

I have been following this [site](http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/forms.html). I want to add an extra field email  along with those available in model. I have

**form.py**

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm 
import django.forms

from new_db.models import Author,Publisher,Book

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,)

    class meta:
        model=Publisher
        fields=['first_name','last_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if kwargs.get('instance'):
        email = kwargs['instance'].email
        kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})['email'] = email
     return super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
 class CreateContact(CreateView):
        model=Publisher
        template_name='CreatePublisher.html'
        form_class=ContactForm
```

and the error I encountered is

```
Exception Value:    ModelForm has no model class specified.
    Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in __init__, line 238
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a typo

```
class meta:
```

Should be

```
class Meta:
```

Note the case.

More here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance

Comment: I have changed the email form to required='false' though it prompts this field is required.

Comment: 'false' and False are not the same

Comment: How can I redirect the page to other pages after the data are submitted. it is redirecting to a page and even i have changed template <form action='.......'> it's not working